# Using numpy to apply a sepia effect to a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In numpy I'm looking to take a 3d array of colour values (2d to represent an image, where each pixel is an RGB colour) and apply a sepia filter for it. Assuming a colour is defined by `r, g, b`, the colour that should be returned after applying a sepia filter to it is:

```
sepia_r = .393*r + .769*g + .189&b
sepia_g = .349*r + .686*g + .168*b
sepia_b = .272*r + .534*g + .131*b
```

What would be the fastest way to get this done in real time with a large array (presumably an 1080x864 array of 3 long vectors)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the standard image array organization of `(height, width, channels)`, you can use `numpy` matrix multiplication directly out of the box.

```
from skimage.data import lena  # Color image version of lena. If you don't have skimage, use any image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = lena().astype(float) / 256.
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img)

sepia_filter = np.array([[.393, .769, .189],
                         [.349, .686, .168],
                         [.272, .534, .131]])

# here goes the filtering
sepia_img = img.dot(sepia_filter.T)

# Unfortunately your filter lines do not have unit sum, so we need to rescale
sepia_img /= sepia_img.max()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(sepia_img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the call to img.dot() doesn't work because the arrays are different sizes (at least in numpy 1.6.1 and scipy 0.9.0)

Comment: Works in `1.6.1` for me. This code is copy+pasteable. Try it! Matrices do not have to have the same size to be multipliable. What is necessary is that there are *two corresponding axes*, one in the first matrix, one in the second. This is the case here: The last (the color-) axis of `img` has length 3 and the axis 0 of `sepia_filter.T` does, too. I can use `numpy.dot` directly, out of the box, because it uses the last axis in the first array and the second-to-last axis in the second array, and those are exactly the ones I need. If one needs different or several ones, one can use `np.tensordot`

Comment: I get this error "ValueError: matrices are not aligned" on that line.  Might be because I'm using the black-and-white version of that image, not the one from skimage?

Comment: Yes, the one from `scipy.misc.lena` is 8 bit gray scale. I didn't want my example to depend on `skimage` but it is the easiest place to get the color version if you have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

On my experience with numpy speed, always try to find a global instruction doing the whole job.
I should arrange an array with the r values, another with the g values and a last one with the b values, and use multiply :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html